# equation with latex

Tags: equations, amsmath

I am trying to write this equation with latex:

[image]

this is the code I wrote:

```
\begin{equation}\label{1}

\min \sum_{i=1}^{$\infty$} $u_j$ (L.B.H) - \sum_{i=1}^{N} \emph{$l_i$}.\emph{$b_i$}.\emph{$h_i$}

\end{equation}
```

but I get this error:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> $
```

I don't know where is the missing `$`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Mico Are you really sure? I'd say it's the empty line...

Comment: @campa - Your're right. There are (at least) two errors: The first error is the blank line, which generates  the "Missing $ inserted." error message. The second error, caused by the spurious `$` symbols in the upper limit of summation, generates a different error message: "Missing { inserted"...

Answer (score 6):

First of all, empty lines are not allowed in displayed math environments (like `equation`), remove those. Second, you are in math mode, so there is no need for `$\infty$`, `\infty` alone is correct. Finally, the `\emph` doesn't really do anything useful I think, I would remove them and the dollar signs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\min \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} u_j (L.B.H) - \sum_{i=1}^{N} l_i.b_i.h_i
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Samuel Not my typo, that's copied from the question. But thanks, will fix.

Comment: Using periods for multiplication is not usual in mathematics

Comment: @egreg I find it odd myself, and if it were me I'd use `\cdot` or nothing.

Comment: @egreg It depends on what you are taught. During my secondary school period, my math teacher told the class to not use the `x` symbol for multiplication like primary school taught us, and instead to use a period. I switched to using `*` during college because that's what programmers use.

Comment: @Nzall `*` looks awful I think. And periods are of course useless if you have decimal numbers and use a period there as well.

Comment: @Nzall A *centered* period, I suppose.

Comment: @egreg no, a normal period. Of course, we did use a comma to indicate decimals, not a period.